# Group By Quarterly Avg and Get Values That Were Used in Avg Calculation -pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, aggregate

I have a `df` like this,

```
          time  value
0   2019-07-30  124.00
1   2019-07-19  123.00
2   2019-08-28  191.46
3   2019-10-25  181.13
4   2019-11-01  24.23
5   2019-11-13  340.00
6   2020-01-01  36.12
7   2020-01-25  56.12
8   2020-01-30  121.00
9   2020-02-04  115.62
10  2020-02-06  63.62
```

I want to group by quarterly average and get the values that were used in average calculation. Something like below.

```
Year  Quarter    Values                              Avg
2019  Q3         124, 123, 191                       146
2019  Q4         181.13, 24.23, 340                  181.78
2020  Q1         36.12, 26.12, 121, 115.62, 63.62    72.96
```

How can I achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with quarter periods created by [`Series.dt.quarter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.quarter.html) with join values converted to `string`s and `mean` in named aggregations:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

df1 = (df.assign(Year = df['time'].dt.year,
                 Q = 'Q' + df['time'].dt.quarter.astype(str),
                 vals = df['value'].astype(str))
         .groupby(['Year','Q'])
         .agg(Values=('vals', ', '.join), Avg = ('value','mean'))
         .reset_index())
print (df1)

   Year   Q                              Values         Avg
0  2019  Q3                124.0, 123.0, 191.46  146.153333
1  2019  Q4                181.13, 24.23, 340.0  181.786667
2  2020  Q1  36.12, 56.12, 121.0, 115.62, 63.62   78.496000
```

EDIT:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

df1 = (df.groupby(df['time'].dt.to_period('Q').rename('YearQ'))['value']
         .agg([('Values', lambda x: ', '.join(x.astype(str))),('Avg','mean')])
         .reset_index()
         .assign(Year = lambda x: x['YearQ'].dt.year,
                 Q = lambda x: 'Q' + x['YearQ'].dt.quarter.astype(str))
         .reindex(['Year','Q','Values','Avg'], axis=1))
print (df1)
   Year   Q                              Values         Avg
0  2019  Q3                124.0, 123.0, 191.46  146.153333
1  2019  Q4                181.13, 24.23, 340.0  181.786667
2  2020  Q1  36.12, 56.12, 121.0, 115.62, 63.62   78.496000
```

Comment: This is awesome, one thing, I edited my post, if I can have `quarter` column separate. That would fulfill  :)

Comment: I am getting an error: `TypeError: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'`. its here `.agg(Values=('vals', ', '.join)`. Any suggestions

Comment: @user9431057 Is possible upgrade pandas to last version?

Comment: I just started using `statsmodel` library and it is dependent on my current pandas version. That was already a pain to install. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Create a [grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html), groupby and reshape the index to year and quarter:

```
grouper = pd.Grouper(key='time',freq='Q')
res = (df
       .assign(temp = df.value.astype(str))
       .groupby(grouper)
       .agg(Values=('temp', ','.join),
            Avg = ('value',np.mean)
           )

      )

res.index = [res.index.year, 'Q' + res.index.quarter.astype(str)]
res.index = res.index.set_names(['Year','Quarter'])


                       Values                   Avg
Year    Quarter     
2019    Q3       123.0,124.0,191.46             146.153333
        Q4       181.13,24.23,340.0             181.786667
2020    Q1       36.12,56.12,121.0,115.62,63.62 78.496000
```